# Como centralizar uma informação para todos os TDs pelo CSS?

Tags: css

Estou com um monte de `<td>` e preciso delas centralizadas. Gostaria de fazer pelo CSS, por exemplo

```
td {
   puxar por aqui.
}
```

Isso em vez de colocar `align="center"` em todos os tds.

Como fazer isso, afetando todas as células de tabela que houver na página?

Answer (score 6):

```
td {
   text-align: center;     /* alinhamento horizontal */
   vertical-align: middle; /* alinhamento vertical */
}
```

Essa regra se aplicaria a todas as TDs, a menos que alguma regra posterior ou mais específica sobrescreva essas propriedades de alinhamento no seu CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar:

```
td{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar colocar um id para a *table* se ela já não tiver e após isso aplicar o estilo que deseja para todos os `td`

```css
#teste td{
  text-align: center;
};
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Posição</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="teste">
        <tr>
            <td>Leonardo</td>
            <td>1º Colocado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Batman</td>
            <td>2º Colocado</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Homer Simpson</td>
            <td>3º Colocado</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ou também existe a opção de você criar uma classe no e definir o estilo dela pelo css.

Ex:

```
.td-alinhado-centro{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Então você teria que atribuir essa classe para todos os td's que você deseja que seja alinhado desse jeito.

Answer (score 0):

A  mais externa ao  você deve colocar a propriedade `text-align:center;` , e o  coloque a propriedade `margin:auto;`

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
    <td>Alinhado</td>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .container{
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     text-align:center;
   }

   .container td{
     margin:auto;
   }
```

Exemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/dbpu5506/

Comment: Margens laterais automáticas para alinhamento só fazem sentido em blocos, não em TDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr><td>Alinhar item ao centro</td></tr>
```

td{
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: center;
}

Ou então se você nãoquiser mover todos os itens de futuras tabelas,você deve cria uma classe ai atribui uma determinada margem aos elementos.